# Magento2 Rest PUT API return payload of default store instead of the target store

Tags: api, rest, magento2, multistore

I'm experiencing a problem with PUT API requests with Magento 2.3.5.

I send the requests to endpoints like:
/rest/STORECODE/V1/products/PRODUCT_CODE

The data are properly stored on the right store having store code STORECODE, but the API response payload contains data of the default store, instead of STORECODE.

How can I get the data written on STORECODE without being forced to do another GET to the same endpoint /rest/STORECODE/V1/products/PRODUCT_CODE?
The GET to /rest/STORECODE/V1/products/PRODUCT_CODE returns the properly data I wrote (that I was expecting to be the return payload of the PUT)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

we found out that the issue was caused by an extension that was not properly handling emulations.

Answer (score 0):

Using path:

> /rest/default/V1/products/PRODUCT_CODE/

Add store in header